# Oracle Remote Scheduler Agent 11.2.0.1 on Win 2008 Server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

OK, this is an odd one. Installed just the remote scheduler agent (11.2.0.1) onto the Win2008 Server, registered it to the database, tested a remote job that just ran a simple DOS .bat file that does nothing more than log "hey I ran" to a local file. Everything worked fine. Repeatedly tested it - all good.

Added an install of the Oracle 11.2.0.1 Client onto the same server so that my remote job could call back to the database, and boom - now scheduler agent will not run any DOS command - it is failing on launching cmd.exe, and always returning an error number 255.

Job from the DB (unchanged from when it worked):

```
 BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name             => 'test_win_job2',
    job_type             => 'EXECUTABLE',
    number_of_arguments  => 2,
    job_action           => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe',
    auto_drop            => TRUE,
    enabled              => FALSE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value('test_win_job2',1,'/c');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value('test_win_job2',2,'c:\oracleagent\test_script.bat');
--
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute('test_win_job2', 'credential_name', 'NEW_WIN_CREDENTIAL');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute('test_win_job2', 'destination', '142.00.00.26:9000');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable('test_win_job2');
END;
/
```

Excerpt from the agent.log file on the Win box:

```
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Received connection from 142.53.204.216:45907
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Using existing spare worker thread
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Assigned connection to 142.53.204.216:45907
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Incremented connections to 1
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Ignoring header: Host Value: 142.53.57.26:8090
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Source Value: p7214.some.agency.ca
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Source-DB Value: CGNSDEV
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Date Value:  2016-07-13 13:52:39.165595000America/Toronto EDT
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Source-Port Value: 8085
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Nonce Value: OEY7pLrMFbK/hT+evALZsw==
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Mac Value: 1M8roBa3lRobQGpb7mLL3V+aPvU=
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Action Value: RUN
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Command Value: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Id Value: 326021
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Name Value: TEST_WIN_JOB2
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Subname Value: 
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Owner Value: JOBMGMT_APP_CODE
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Username Value: wasadmin
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Password Value: *
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Domain Value: 
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Request-Id Value: 2797301621
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Start Value:  2016-07-13 13:52:38.946324000America/New_York EDT
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job-Scheduled-Start Value:  2016-07-13 13:52:38.853560000America/New_York EDT
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Credential-Owner Value: JOBMGMT_APP_CODE
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Credential-Name Value: NEW_WIN_CREDENTIAL
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Ignoring header: Log-ID Value: 81795
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Argument1 Value: /c
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Argument2 Value: c:\oracleagent\test_script.bat
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Ignoring header: Connection Value: close
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Database authentication check passed
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Decremented connections to 0
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Incremented running jobs to 1
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Log ID: job_326021_18 Name: JOBMGMT_APP_CODE.TEST_WIN_JOB2 Source: p7214.ic.gc.ca : 8085 Source DB: CGNSDEV Command: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Argument 1 : /c
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Argument 2 : c:\oracleagent\test_script.bat
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Passed SystemDrive=C:
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Passed SystemRoot=C:\Windows
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Passed Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\IBM\DB2\BIN;C:\IBM\DB2\FUNCTION;C:\IBM\DB2\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client\bin
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Passed ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
2016.07.13 12:52:28 CDT Thread: 12 Passed OS=Windows_NT
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Job terminated with error number: 255. Duration: 1.435 seconds
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Results: job_owner=JOBMGMT_APP_CODE&job_name=TEST_WIN_JOB2&job_subname=&start_date=1468432348896&run_duration=1435&cpu_used=&error_number=255&error_text=&output_text=&request_id=2797301621&add_info=EXTERNAL_LOG_ID%3D%22job_326021_18%22%2C%0AUSERNAME%3D%22wasadmin%22&submit=Submit
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Returning job results to :http://p7214.ic.some.agency:8085/remote_scheduler_agent/submit_job_results2
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Connected to :p7214.some.agency.ca
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Sent data to submit_job_results :p7214.some.agency.ca
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Oracle Scheduler Remote Job Run Completion
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Received: Job Run Completion Successful!
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Decremented running jobs to 0
2016.07.13 12:52:30 CDT Thread: 12 Adding thread to spareThreads
```

And if I check the Windows Event Log I see:

```
           jssu.exe
            0.0.0.0
            4bb1e0d1
            ntdll.dll
            6.1.7601.17725
            4ec4aa8e
            c0000374
            00000000000c40f2
            39c
            01d1dd2f52920e10
            C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client\bin\jssu.exe
            C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
            90ff6867-4922-11e6-906b-000c29f63d9e

The information attached is:
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: jssu.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 4bb1e0d1
P4: StackHash_dcf9
P5: 6.1.7601.17725
P6: 4ec4aa8e
P7: c0000374
P8: 00000000000c40f2
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_jssu.exe_f02bd96ab90965af7744491b05a8a4b136aedab_1d31148f

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: ec2e1259-491c-11e6-906b-000c29f63d9e
Report Status: 0
```

Does anyone have any clue why the client install from the same distribution has killed the remote scheduler agent? OR what might be required to have them both located on the same server? I can look at OS options other than 2008, but just wondering if anyone had seen anything remotely like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the 11.2.0.1 executable, and patching jssu.exe from the 11.2.0.4 download resolved it.